# Passing pointer to pointer to buffer in ctypes

Tags: python, c, ctypes

I'm trying to grab image data from a camera using ctypes and python.

Very basically, the documentation says that I should connect to the device, set resolution, output window, frame rate and trigger mode (all, apparently successful). Then, I should open an image sequence, and either start grabbing frames, or trigger the camera at moments when I want to get a frame. This is all reasonably clear. Where things start to go wrong is in accessing the frame data. In C, the code should look something like this:

```
// Snap two images into buffers
// Buffer size is decided by image resolution
// Here assuming a image is 800*600
BeginHVDevice(1,&hDevice1); //Initialize camera 1
HVSetOutputWindow(hDevice1, 0, 0, 800, 600);
//bunch of other settings as well


BYTE Buffer1[800 * 600]; // Buffer for one image
BYTE Buffer2[800 * 600]; // Buffer for a second image 
BYTE *ppBuffer[2]; //This array keeps the pointer to each buffer 
ppBuffer[0] = Buffer1;
ppBuffer[1] = Buffer2;
void *nParam
long *callBack

HVOpenSnap(hDevice1, callBack, nParam); //note that I don't use call backs so the last two params are not used 
HVSnapShot(hhv, ppBuffer, 2); //last argument is just the number of frames to collect
HVCloseSnap(hhv);
```

The problem is the buffer used to store the data. I've tried creating a string buffer of the correct size and passing that byref. I've tried creating integer buffers, long buffers. I get three results: the buffer is never touched (all null values), the program hard crashes and has to restarted (I would guess that python tries to write to an invalid address at this point), or there is a type error.

The current python code looks like this

```
ailt_lib = WinDLL("HVDAILT")
util_lib = WinDLL("HVUtil")
raw_2_rgb_lib = WinDLL("Raw2Rgb")


open_snap = ailt_lib.HVOpenSnap
open_snap.restype = c_int
open_snap.argtypes = [HANDLE, POINTER(c_long), c_void_p]

close_snap = ailt_lib.HVCloseSnap
close_snap.restype = c_int
close_snap.argtypes = [HANDLE]


stop_snap = ailt_lib.HVStopSnap
stop_snap.restype = c_int
stop_snap.argtypes = [HANDLE,]

start_snap = ailt_lib.HVStartSnap
start_snap.restype = c_int
start_snap.argtypes = [HANDLE, POINTER(c_char_p*buf_size), c_int]

click = ailt_lib.HVTriggerShot
click.restype = c_int
click.argtype = [POINTER(HANDLE),]

#Bunch of code to initialise the camera. All apparently succeeds

print open_snap(cam_handle, byref(c_long(0)), c_void_p(None))
storage = c_char_p*buf_size
buf = storage()
storage_ptr = pointer(buf)
print start_snap(cam_handle, storage_ptr, 1)
print click(cam_handle)
```

I think, in this case, the problem is that I simply don't know how to generate the correct form of buffer that should be passed to start_snap.

Comment: Ah, sorry, yes, its the same as for HVSnapShot. HVStartSnap(HHV hhv, BYTE **ppBuffer, int nSum)

Comment: I also tried using `buf=(c_char*buf_size)()`, but it also crashes python.

Comment: Also, interestingly, if I change the code to use HVSnapShot, which takes exactly the same argument types, python throws as type error rather than crashing.

Comment: Use `POINTER(POINTER(c_char))` in `argtypes`. Then call as follows: `buf = (c_char * buf_size)(); pbuf = (POINTER(c_char) * 1)(buf); start_snap(cam_handle, pbuf, 1)`. You can scale this to more than 1 buffer.

Comment: Yes :). Strangely enough startsnap/trigger/stopsnap still doesn't work. But snapshot does. Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: yes, I spotted the typo earlier but did not update here. And, yes, it should be HANDLE not POINTER(HANDLE). The fact that the prototype for open_snap is wrong is probably why snapshot works and open_snap doesn't.

Comment: Thanks, but I think I have it worked out now. The key point is: the code is at work in the lab providing mountains of data now. Many thanks for your help :)